# oData Model submitChanges error callback function not executed

Tags: submitchanges

I would like to know when I use the `submitChanges` of `sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel`, and have a success and error callback function. Even if the request failed the success handler gets called.

My code example is below:

```
onSave: function() {                            
    this.getModel().submitChanges({
        success: function(oData, oReponse) { 
            //Do something for success                      
        },
        error: function(oError) { 
            //Do something for error
        }
    });                                 
}
```

Comment: What HTTP status code is being returned?

Comment: Hi there the HTTP status code I get from memory was 202 or 200